# how can I plot two variables (inside a definite integral) against each other

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I want to plot x against y in this relation:
[image: relation]

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code, this will increase your chance  to get helpful answers!

Comment: Your variable `h` is not defined, and you need to capitalize `Exp` (not `exp`).

Comment: 1- it is type mistake, y is true (not h) 2- ok thanks I correct Exp.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html).

For example:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Integrate[Sin[x  y  + x + (y - Pi/2) x  z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}], 
    {x, -Pi,  Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, PlotRange -> Full, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

To show a single contour, say the contour where `Integrate[Sin[x  y  + x + (y - Pi/2) x  z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}] == Pi/2` you can use

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Integrate[Sin[x  y  + x + (y - Pi/2) x  z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}] == Pi/2], 
 {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], ContourShading -> None, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the option `Contours -> {Pi/2}`:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@Integrate[Sin[x  y  + x + (y - Pi/2) x  z], {z, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  {x, -Pi,  Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, Exclusions -> None, ContourStyle -> Thick, 
 ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> Full, Contours -> {Pi/2}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks kglr. I will try it. but I have a question. What about the right side of this relation? The left side is equals to 2pi (=2pi). It seems that this is an integral equation.

Comment: `@Rojan, if you `Integrate[f[x,y,z], {z, 0,2pi}]` is a function of (x,y). If you call that function `g[x,y]`, you can use `ContourPlot[ g[x,y] == level, {x,...}, {y...}]` to get the locus of `{x,y}` points that satisfy `g[x,y] == level`.